# Can't find installed linux in bootmenu

Tags: linux, boot, bios, grub, uefi

I just tried to install Linux server to my ThinkCentre m92p. First I tried to install Ubuntu server. Installation was completed successfully, but I couldn't find anything to boot in my boot menu. Then I decided to try Arch Linux installation because it gives me more control.

State now:

Arch Linux is completed. I see absolutely nothing in my boot menu excepting disc, DVD and network boot. I can start the Linux using installation USB, which can be found in my boot menu. There I can boot live GRUB using which I can boot Arch Linux installed on my HD. Arch works perfectly.

I tried to install GRUB on HD. All files are present in `/boot/EFI/GRUB/grubwhatever.efi`, `/boot/grub` folder if present too. I even tried to create a new entry using efibootmgr and adding active parameter to it using -a. Nothing helped.

Output of efibootmgr -v:

[image: Log]

[image: SameLogDifferentPhoto]

I can see data outputs there and don't know what does it mean. There is no information about data param in docs.

The interesting fact is that the disc which I can boot from contains shorter data content - all the same length. Even dp content does look different.

Could you help me please somehow? I spent a lot of time trying to address it. I'm lost.

(I hope this question isn't off-topic here. If so, please give me advice on where to ask)

Comment: Try if the [Super Grub2 Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/) can fix your boot problem.